# How to run ansible from linux to deploy on windows machines

Tags: windows, authorization, ansible, kerberos

Here is what I have after setting kerberos according to ansible:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.COM
…
[realms]
        MY.DOMAIN.COM = {
                default_domain = my.domain.com
                kdc = <domain-controller-server>.my.domain.com
                kpasswd_server = <domain-controller-server>.my.domain.com
        }
…
[domain_realm]
        .my.domain.com = MY.DOMAIN.COM
…
```

I was able to create a kerberos ticket, here is my output:

```
root@alex-VirtualBox:/etc/ansible# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: <user_name>@MY.DOMAIN.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
04/07/2016 13:58:52  04/07/2016 23:58:52  krbtgt/MY.DOMAIN.COM@MY.DOMAIN.COM
       renew until 04/08/2016 13:58:48
04/07/2016 14:02:20  04/07/2016 23:58:52  HTTP/<windows-target-server>.my.domain.com@MY.DOMAIN.COM
       renew until 04/08/2016 13:58:48
```

So what I am trying to do is run ansible playbook or even a simple command on . But I am getting this error which I am pretty sure have nothing to do with ansible:

```
root@alex-VirtualBox:/etc/ansible# ansible windows -m win_ping --ask-vault-pass
Vault password: 
<windows-target-server>.my.domain.com | FAILED! => {
        "failed": true, 
        "msg": "kerberos: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377)), plaintext: 401 Unauthorized."
    }
```

I even went ahead and created the keytab file:

```
> ktutil
  ktutil:  addent -password -p <user_name>@MY.DOMAIN.COM -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
  provide password
  ktutil:  wkt <user_name>.keytab
  ktutil:  quit
```

But then I get different error:

```
root@alex-VirtualBox:/etc/ansible# ansible windows -m win_ping --ask-vault-pass
n2-2wbp-wbsvr01.na.msds.rhi.com | FAILED! => {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "kerberos: (('An invalid name was supplied', 131072), ('Success', 100001)), plaintext: 401 Unauthorized."
}
```

Comment: Same problem here, but only for one host. Did you manage to work by yourself?

Comment: No luck so far. There is a similar issue open on https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15332

Comment: Try adding the following variables on group_vars:
`ansible_winrm_scheme: https`
`ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos`
`ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore`

Comment: That worked, thank you! Oddly enough after it worked, I removed all but "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore" and it started working. I remember having this there before.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the IP and Hostname of your Windows Host entry in /etc/hosts file and then try: https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/21#issuecomment-58958732 , https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/issues/21#issuecomment-59084178

PS:
'Server not found in Kerberos database' - That usually means that the Linux host where you're running `kinit` is not joined to the domain (ie, it doesn't have a properly configured computer account in the domain). The existing docs unhelpfully omit that requirement...

Comment: Actually I got rid of the 'Server not found in Kerberos' Now i keep getting 401 authorization errors - as the last one paragraph in my post.

Comment: Adding ip/hostname  entry did not make it work either - same authorization error.

Comment: A quick important note, one of my issues was that the machine was pointing to a wrong IP address on Microsoft AD. Always use `nslookup` to make sure that there is nothing wrong with DNS